# C++ Reading Registry When using Service fails but the same succeds in Console

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, service

I have to read some Registry Value as soon as the program starts. The Code does works correctly and gives the Registry Value I seek, if the code is compiled and run from Command prompt. But If I create the service and attach the exe to the service using following code:

```
sc create someservice start=auto binpath= "PATH to EXE of Code"
```

and run the service I don't get the desired value. I have attached the complete code. I have logged the result of each step also.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

SERVICE_STATUS ServiceStatus; 
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hStatus; 

int WriteToLog(const char *);
std::string GetLPInstalledPath();

std::string GetLPInstalledPath()
    {
        HKEY hKey;
        char buf[255];
        DWORD dwType;
        DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
        std::string ss="";
        const char* subkey = "Software\\\\Logpoint\\\\InstalledPath";
        WriteToLog(" Inside GetLPInstalledPath") ;
        if( RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,subkey,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            WriteToLog("Opened the Registry Key");
        dwType = REG_SZ;
        if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"path",0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
        ss = buf;       
        WriteToLog(ss.c_str());
        }
        else
        {
        WriteToLog(" Cound not find the value");

        }           
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteToLog(" Cannot Open the Installed Registry Path");

        }

        return ss;
    }

int WriteToLog(const char* str)
{
    //const char *logfile = "D:\\ubuntu_share\\lpa\\lpa_c\\build_win\\src\\lpa\\sample.txt";
    FILE* log;
    log = fopen("C:\\lpa\\sample.txt", "a+");
    if (log == NULL)
        return -1;
    fprintf(log, "%s\n", str);
    fclose(log);
    return 0;
}

int Run()
{
    WriteToLog("Run");
    WriteToLog("entering infinite loop of main thread ");
    while(1);
    WriteToLog("end of main thread ");
    return 0;
}

void ControlHandler(DWORD request) 
{ 
    //LOG4CPLUS_INFO(root,  "ControlHandler: Entry";
    switch(request) 
    { 
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: 
            //WriteToLog("Monitoring stopped.");
            WriteToLog( "ControlHandler: SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP Request");
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0; 
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
            if(SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus)==FALSE)
            {
                WriteToLog("ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error");
            }
            return; 

        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN: 
           // WriteToLog("Monitoring shutdown.");
            WriteToLog("ControlHandler: SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN Request");
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0; 
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
            if(SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
            {
                WriteToLog("ServiceCtrlHandler: SetServiceStatus returned error");
            }
            return; 

        case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
            return;
        default:
            WriteToLog("ServiceCtrlHandler");
            break;
    } 

    // Report current status
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus,  &ServiceStatus);
    WriteToLog("ServiceCtrlHandler: Exit");
    return; 
} 

void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    //WriteToLog("at ServiceMain");
    WriteToLog("ServiceMain");
    int error; 

    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType        = SERVICE_WIN32; 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_START_PENDING; 
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted   = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint         = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint           = 0; 

    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(
        "MemoryStatus", 
        (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler); 
    if (hStatus == NULL) 
    { 
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        WriteToLog("ServiceMain: RegisterServiceCtrlHandler returned error");
        return; 
    }  

    // We report the running status to SCM. 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING; 
    if(SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus)==FALSE)
    {
        WriteToLog("ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error");
    }

    WriteToLog("ServiceMain: Performing Service Start Operations");
    Run();
    WriteToLog("ServiceMain: Performing Cleanup Operations");
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 3;

    if (SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus) == FALSE)
    {
        WriteToLog("ServiceMain: SetServiceStatus returned error");
    }
    WriteToLog("ServiceMain: Exit");
    return; 
}


int StartLpaService()
{

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = "MemoryStatus";
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;

    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;
    // Start the control dispatcher thread for our service
    if(StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable)  == FALSE)
    {
        WriteToLog("StartLpaService: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned error");
        return GetLastError ();
    }
    WriteToLog("Main: Exit");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    std::string pa = GetLPInstalledPath();
#ifdef SERVICE_DEBUG
    WriteToLog("SERVICE_DEBUG");
    Sleep(15000);
#endif
    StartLpaService();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that if the service of the program is started, no Registry value is written, but running directly from command prompt is giving the value. How do I solve this Issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking in `HKCU`, the registry hive for the current user. So the most plausible explanation for what you describe is simply that the service is running under a different user. That is the service runs under a user account other than the interactive user.

Comment: how do I know under which user account service is running? So Should I write the value other than HKCU?

Comment: @SarvagyaPant: You configure the user when you create the service. The usual solution is `HKLM`.

Comment: Well, it depends on what the problem is I suppose. You could try reading from HKLM, but presumably you read from HKCU because that's where the information you want lives. So, ask yourself this, where is the information that you want to read?

Comment: Also the default way service is created as LocalSystem. Does this mean I have to use HKLM?

Comment: You have to remember that we have no idea what this registry key is, why you expect it to exist, what you will do with it and so on. Remember that we just answer the questions that are asked. You asked why the service could not see the key. I tried to answer that. Now, if all parties involved use HKLM, then the key will be shared. Modulo 32/64 bit registry redirection. You almost certainly don't want your service to be `LocalSystem`. That is bad practise.

Comment: The Registry Key specified above will contain the Installed path, which will be written by Wix. I tried your suggestion ie I changed the service to Current User(that required password), and this worked. But this is infeasible as I want to just get the value from registry directly as soon as service starts.

Comment: Please do try to remember that we don't have a clear understanding of your goals. This was a question about registry access from a service. Please don't expect us to understand the intricacies of your WiX installer. If you want a location in the registry that is shared between users, then you need HKLM. If you want per-user settings, then use HKCU. Armed with that information and knowledge you can work out how to proceed.